# Card Component using React MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns, material-ui, card

I am not able to create the structure of the below card. My card Media is just not loading and no image is appearing. Please help
Due to strict company policies, I cannot share the real picture of the card. I have created the dummy image for the reference card. Can someone please help me with this. I am struck for a day and none of senior cares! Can someone please send the code structure for the below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft4fX.jpg)

I am not able to figure out how to align both image and text horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help, can you please update your post to show what you've tried code wise? Company policy prevents from sharing code, but you can make a mini reproduceable example of your code for others to check and see where you can improve :)